# REACT JS - Working on eshop-like project, got stuck with product filters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So hello. I've been working on my own stuff as I believe it is the best way to learn things. So I got stuck, I am quite new to this react thing. I got this code, as you can see I have few checkboxes there, and what I want to achieve is to check the box to filter (hide) products from the array. I kinda got to the point where I don't know what should I do next, I know I need to put something into constructor, but I can't really figure out what. Can you please help me with that? Thanks!

```js
class Shop extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        //I should put something here?
      }
    }

    render(){

        let checkbox = (a) => {
         this.setState({cpu: a.target.checked});
  
         
        }

        return (<div>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={checkbox} name="cpu" id="cpu"></input>
                
            //I will do these later, so far I'd be happy to get cpu filter to work.    
            
            <input type="checkbox" name="gpu" id="gpu"></input> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="psu" id="psu"></input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mb" id="mb"></input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ram" id="ram"></input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="case" id="case"></input>
            
            {products.filter(product =>{
            if (true) {
                return true;
            }
        }).map((shop) =>
          <>
          <div id="prodinfo">
           <p id="pname">{shop.name}</p>
           <p id="pprice">{shop.price}</p>
           <img src={shop.image} id="pimg" alt=""></img>
           
           </div>
        
        
          </>)} </div>);
} 
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Shop/>,
  document.getElementById('maincontent')
);
```

```css
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }


  /* HEADER */

  header {
      background-color: rgb(57,184,231);
      height: 9em;
      border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  }

  .mainheader {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 70em;
  }

.socialnetworks {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    margin: -7px 0 0 0;

    width: 100%;

    background-color: rgb(0,170,203);
    height: 20px;
}

.socialnetworks i {
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: white;

    font-size: 20px;
}

.socialnetworks i:first-child:hover {
    color: rgb(66, 103, 178);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.socialnetworks i:last-child:hover {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.socicons {
    padding-right: 410px;
}

.socialnetworks i:last-child {
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;

    max-width: 18%;

    font-size: 60px;

    color: white;
    
}

.logo span {
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.menu {
    text-align: center;
}

.menu span {
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.menu span:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(33, 97, 194);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.menu a:last-child {
    padding: 0;
}

.basket {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    right: 60px;
}

.basket span:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.basket span {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;

    background-color: rgb(0, 41, 128);
    color: whitesmoke;
}

/* MAIN_CONTENT */

#maincontent {

    padding-top: 10em;
    width: 1251px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#prodinfo {
    display: inline-block;
    
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;

    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;

    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}

#pname {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#pprice {
    position: relative;
    top: 165px;
    left: 60px;

    font-size: 20px;
}

#pimg {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 110px;

    height: 160px;
    width: 200px;
}

#pprice::after {
    content: "€";
}

#prodfilters {
    text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a2faab1b70.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="database.js"></script>
    <script src="functions.js" type="text/babel"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>PCzone</title>
</head>

<body>

   <header>
      <div class="socialnetworks">
         <div class="socicons">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"> Facebook</i>
            <i class="fab fa-youtube"> Youtube</i>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mainheader">
         <div class="logo">
            <span>PC</span>zone
         </div>

         <div class="menu">
            <span><a href="">Domov</a></span>
            <span><a href="">Zľavené produkty</a></span>
            <span><a href="">O nás</a></span>
         </div>

         <div class="basket">
            <span><i class="fas fa-shopping-basket">Nákupný košík</i></span>
         </div>

      </div>
   </header>

   <div id="prodfilters">
      <p>Filter produktov</p>
   </div>

   <div id="maincontent">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Shop extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cpu: false,
      gpu: false,
      psu: false,
      mb: false,
      ram: false,
      case: false,
    }
  }
  
  render(){
    let checkbox = (a) => {
      this.setState({ [a.target.name]: a.target.checked });      
    }
  
    return <div>
      {products.map(product=> {
         return <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  onChange={checkbox}
                  name={product.type}
                  id={product.type}
                />
      })}
                          
      {products.filter(product => {
        return this.state[product.type];
      }).map((shop) =>
        <div id="prodinfo">
          <p id="pname">{shop.name}</p>
          <p id="pprice">{shop.price}</p>
          <img src={shop.image} id="pimg" alt="" />
        </div>)}
    </div>;
```

Okay, so.. First of all, you need to set initial state to be able to trigger re-renders in you components (this what [@alexsc _'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71008375/13747848) answer was about).

Second of all, if you're trying to filter on an array of objects, you must have a field that you can use for that (**note that I added** a type variable that would contain the **type of cpu or gpu, etc..** for each product). The React way to render multiple elements with similar values are usually done with mapping the related array (**notice the mapping** of products that **returns an input element**).

Following this logic, the third modification I made on your code was the **filtering of products**. This might not make any sense whatsoever, but when you click on an input element, it will trigger a re-render, due to the modification of a state member. This is why you need to have initial state and this is why I put the line, `this.state[product.type]` in the filter. With this, React will detect a change in state and will attempt to re-render your component, which calls the filter method again with updated values.

To make it more clear, let's say you filter by `cpu`. You'll **click on the input which says `cpu`**. This will set the `cpu` state variable to `true`. React detects that the state has changed so it attempts a re-render. Then it'll call the filter method on your `products` array again and `this.state[product.type]` will eventually be `this.state['cpu']` which will evaluate to `true`.

**NOTE:** If you're unfamiliar with any of the used syntax, you should checkout the [docs](https://javascript.info/object)

Comment: Thanks, kinda what I was looking for. I have 25 items stored in the array and it showed 25 checkboxes to check, but I think I can fix that myself hopefuly.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that you should **map the array**, `array.map(item => item.type)` and create a **`new Set([...array])`**. This will create an only `type` set that **contains only one of each type**

Answer (score 0):

In

```
this.state = {
        //I should put something here?
      }
```

You should put the initial value of cpu, in this case i think you want to filter the products when the user checks the checkbox, so the initial value of the state variable is gonna be false, like this:

```
 this.state = {
        cpu:false
      }
```

So when the value of cpu is true you should filter all the products that are an cpu.